# 'title' does not have default value error 500 in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Hi I am trying to create a post using form data, because I have a file input to upload images. I am really struggling with getting the upload file to work. I get an error 500 when I try to create a post, with the message

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'title' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `posts` ('updated_at', 'created_at') values (2018-01-30 12:31:18, 2018-01-30 12:31:18).

I am not sure what is meant by default value. I checked my `$fillables` and title is definitely there. When I run the following code in my controller right at the top it passes:

```
$request->all();
return response()->json('passed');
```

But when I have the following in my controller it gives the error:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    Post::create($request->all());

    $response = [
        'response' => 'Post Created Successfully',
        'error' => 'Something went wrong'
    ];

    return response()->json($response);
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Create your post</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="post">Post</label>
            <textarea name="post" rows="8" cols="80" id="post" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="image">Add image</label>
            <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Post" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</div>
```

AJAX:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData();
        var fileData = $('#image').prop('files')[0];
        var title = $('#title').val();
        var post = $('#post').val();

        formData.append('fileData', fileData);
        formData.append('title', title);
        formData.append('post', post);

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url:'/post/create/create',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                formData: formData
            },
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: 'json',

            success:function(response){
                toastr.success(response.response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                toastr.error(error.error)
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my Post model with the fillables:

```
protected $fillable = ['title', 'post', 'user_id', 'uploadImage'];
```

Comment: Please show result of `dd($request->all());`

Comment: It shows an empty array '[]'

Comment: that means you are not getting formData

Comment: What could possibly be wrong with the formdata?

Comment: Pass the data as `data: formData`

Comment: @linktoahref thank you - the array shows now. However I think there is still something wrong with my file upload setup - I still get error 500. This file upload process is very challenging for me.

Comment: What's the error? Please be specific

Comment: That is the problem - my log file takes forever to update and in my network tab under response is just script and under preview the array appears so I do not know what the error is except that it is 500 internal server error

Comment: "_I am not sure what is meant by default value."_ The default value to use when your title is empty. In your migration file you could `$table->string('title')->default('Untitled')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-order to obtain the data from your ajax in your controller, pass the data as

```
data: formData
```

instead of

```
data: {
     formData: formData
}
```

and you could process the information in your controller as

```
public function create(Request $request)
{

    $path = '';

    if ($request->hasFile('fileData')) {
        if ($request->file('fileData')->isValid()) {
            // Upload the file
            $path = $request->fileData->store('your directory');
        }
    }

    $post = Post::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'post' => $request->post,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'uploadImage' => $path
    ]);

    if ($post) {
        return response()->json([
            'response' => 'Post Created Successfully!'
        ]);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'error' => 'Something went wrong!'
    ], 500)

}
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#storing-uploaded-files) on storing uploaded files

Comment: Wow thank, I will try this out and let you know. Many many thanks

Comment: just want to let you know I came right this morning (finally). I struggled with getting the directory and then I realized a mistake on my part but it is working now. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Horcrux Glad I could help!